# Google maps geocoder for OpenStreetMap

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, google-geocoder, restrictions

I use almost exclusively OpenstreetMap, but not for geocoding, because I think Nominatim is not very flexible.

Can I use google geocoder free and unrestricted? Do I need to write on my website that I use google geocoder? Are there any restrictions, like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing?hl=en)

However, I would find that very strange because I **only** use google geocoder.

For clarification:
PHP:

```
$filename="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$_GET['address']."+&sensor=true_or_false";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

$lat=$xml->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lat;
$lon=$xml->result[0]->geometry[0]->location[0]->lng;
```

And these coordinates I use then for OpenStreetMap.

I would be very happy for an answer.

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the terms of use of the Google Geocoding Service

Comment: Read the documentation for the geocoding service. [The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map;](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: If you like we can discuss your problems with nominatim in a different new question if you explain why nominatim lacks for your purporse.

Comment: I can't get a match of a single address in nominatim... I wouldn't mind a paid geocoding only service.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot.

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

Derived from [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)